# Can the human brain move objects without touching them?

Tags: esp

This 2016 YouTube video, *[Best Explanation Of How The Brain Performs TELEKINESIS...On The WEB!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEGf0E3wTl8)* attempts to informally describe how things can be moved with the brain.

I have never seen anyone with this kind of ability.

An internet search shows many people believe you can move items with the mind without touching them. Here are some of the top search results for "is telekinesis possible":

- [This Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Is-telekinesis-theoretically-possible-Do-the-laws-of-nature-allow-it)
- [This wikihow on how to develop the ability](https://www.wikihow.com/Develop-Telekinesis)
- [This tutorial](https://bookofresearch.wordpress.com/2015/06/28/how-to-do-telekinesis/)

Can humans perform telekinesis, i.e. moving items with the mind without touching them?

Comment: I don't think a YouTube video qualifies as a "notable source".

Comment: @DanielRHicks: We have hundreds of questions based on YouTube videos. This particular video hasn't been widely watched, but the concept of telekinesis is clearly notable.

Comment: @Oddthinking Re: notability, the claim in this post is a youtube video with a few thousand views. I don't think that matches [your faq](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2512/46182). That doesn't mean there isn't a notable claim about telekinesis out there. It's just not in this question. The claim as stated could also be improved by wording it in a way that could feasibly be falsified. Testing "Is there a human with this particular ability" is not particularly feasible, and that's what these kinds of questions usually run up against.

Comment: @DeNovo: We both agree that this video hasn't been widely watched. I think we both agree that the fact it is a YouTube video isn't the issue. The FAQ you link to links to [this answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1492/23) about what to do if we think it isn't notable, and part of it is searching for examples. If you do that, you will find that telekinesis has a long history of belief (less now, perhaps, than in the 60's, but it still persists)

Comment: @Oddthinking shouldn't the specific claim, as referenced in the question be notable, and the research demonstrating its notability be in the question? I.e., the claim (this YouTube video demonstrates telekinesis), not the topic (telekinesis), should be notable.

Comment: The narrator says *I just came up with a new theory* and then goes into some speculations not based on any observation. With *I* being someone calling himself *Mad Cat Sphere* from the USA, no further information. Not a notable claim at all.

Comment: @Oddthinking this was confusing to me because of the faq discussion of a quality question, vs. minimal standards. So, to clarify:  any claim is on topic with regards to notability until it is challenged. If one person challenges it, then the claim needs to be edited to demonstrate notability. I will make the edit.

Comment: @DeNovo: I am not sure I understood your comment. This should probably be taken to meta. I think the claim "telekinesis exists" is believed by a large number of people. I think the specific example used to prove notability here is poor. Despite that, we all know fairly precisely what the claim is and that many people believe it, so the question is adequate. If you want to add a better example, please do so. It would be easy to link to Wikipedia for definitions and notability, but it contains the *answer* to the question, so it seems a bit circular.

Comment: @Oddthinking I was just summarizing after more thoroughly reading the many meta discussions about notability. I think it's been discussed enough there, so I won't add to it.

Answer (score 12):

Telekinesis, also known as [psychokinesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychokinesis), is pseudoscientific. There is no quality evidence for it. The conjectures in the video attempting to explain it are without merit.

The Wikipedia page, linked above, includes (indirect) references to several studies that support this. It is difficult to directly link to the findings of, for example, the United States National Academy of Sciences, because much of the parapsychological research was done in the mid-20th Century.

e.g. this [1962 review](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1963-06052-001) that concludes:

> Evidence of PK as a psychological phenomenon is therefore totally lacking.

More recent research is less into whether psychokinesis exists, but why people still believe it exists despite the lack of evidence.

e.g. a [1996 meta-analytic review](https://search.proquest.com/openview/cdfdecc2694f5c8d8fbf174f077055de/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=1819046) or this [2010 qualatitive review](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1348/000712605X72523)